# free to use JBIG2 encoding library for c++

Tags: c++, encoding

I´m searching for a JBIG2 encoding library, which is free to use and runs on Windows.

I found [this](https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc) library, but it is not compilable on Windows. It uses some Linux libraries.
It´s really confusing, too.

Does anyone know an alternative to it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a windows binary of my mentioned library here:
http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/windows-version-jbig2-encoder-jbig2-exe

Answer (score 2):

Did you find [this one](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/blog/tag/jbig2/).  It seems to be free.  EDIT: The underlying source is actually Delphi, but there is a DLL that's usable with C++ (as long as you have MFC).

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded it, but it seems to be not free. I need a key for it. Otherwise it´s a trial.

Comment: Geez, that's what I was afraid of, I didn't try to use the DLL, so I didn't know.  See if someone has made a set of cMake files for the one that runs under Linux (so you can compile it under Windows), or alternatively you can get MSYS or Cygwin and compile under that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried OpenCV library?

I think that it includes also JBIG2 encoding.

Furthermore OPENCV is a cross platform library.

Comment: I didn´t find anything that says "opencv supports the following formats: ", so I`m not really sure if it suports JBIG2 encoding.

Comment: Probably you are right..... try also wxWidgets, that is a very popular c++ library and provides many encoding APIs.